# Trying to build loop that creates the attachment file from scratch and then sends it in an email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have got the email part to work but I am new to loops and the files I need this to create would add up to over 100 (current code is just decoy emails before adapting to the main email list).
I'm struggling to get the code to create the attachment details, it makes the file and saves it for the first loop then throws up a **data type mismatch error** on the `Windows(xm).Select` line before the email code starts:

```
Sub EmailSend()
 
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Back End")
Dim oa As Object
Dim msg As Object
FirstChartPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Redacted.png" 
ChartName = "redacted.png" 
CurrentFile = "Christmas Email.xlsm"  
Set xm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Back End").Range("J" & 9)
   
    
    Set oa = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim last_row As Integer
    
    
    last_row = sh.Range("J65536").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 9 To last_row
    
    
    
    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Workbooks(CurrentFile).Path & "\" & sh.Range("J" & 9)
    Windows("Christmas Email.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(xm).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("C5").Select
    Windows("Christmas Email.xlsm").Activate
   Set msg = oa.createitem(0)
    
        msg.To = sh.Range("H" & i).Value
        msg.Subject = sh.Range("E2").Value
        msg.HTMLBody = MESSAGE HERE
       'If sh.Range("H" & i).Value <> "" Then
            'msg.attachments.Add sh.Range("I" & i).Value
       'End If
    
        msg.display
     
     'msg.Send
     
     Next i
      
    ' MsgBox "Sent"
     
End Sub*
```

I tried to record macro but couldn't fit the loop around it. Have also googled extensively but as I'm still reasonably new to vba a lot of it went over my head. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: `it makes the file and saves it for the first loop then throws up errors before the email code starts`, That isn't helpful. Tell us what the error is

Comment: Type mismatch, debug narrows it down to where it says Windows(xm).Select but I don't know what I could change it too - sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: Is the macro code in `Christmas Email.xlsm` ?

Comment: Yes it is, the plan is to have it all in one workbook and then hit go to create the attachments and send the emails

Comment: You seem to be creating a workbook named as `sh.Range("J" & 9)` but attaching a workbook named `sh.Range("I" & i).Value`. What are in columns J and I and how do the attachments vary or are they just copies of the template ?

Comment: The part which says sh.Range("I" & i).Value hasn't been edited yet - I'm trying to create the sheet first so that will be later changed to sh.Range("J" & 9) which is where the file name is that was created e.g Customer Name Christmas Email.xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Worksheet.Copy` will create a new workbook without copy/paste.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub EmailSend()
 
    Dim sh As Worksheet, wbTmpl As Workbook
    Dim oa As Object, msg As Object
    Dim last_row As Long, i As Long
    Dim folder As String, attachFile As String
    
    Set oa = CreateObject("outlook.Application")
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Back End")
    folder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    
    With sh
        last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
        If last_row < 9 Then
            MsgBox "No data in col H below row " & last_row, vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        For i = 9 To last_row
            If Len(.Range("H" & i).Value) > 0 Then
            
                ' create attachment
                attachFile = folder & sh.Range("J" & 9)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template").Copy
                ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True, Filename:=attachFile
   
                ' send email
                Set msg = oa.createitem(0)
                msg.To = .Range("H" & i).Value
                msg.Subject = .Range("E2").Value
                msg.HTMLBody = "MESSAGE HERE"
                msg.attachments.Add attachFile
                msg.display
                msg.Send
                
            End If
        Next i
    End With
      
    MsgBox i - 9 & " Emails Sent", vbInformation
     
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You really should concentrate on getting the basics working first, before putting the full solution together, because you have a lot of minor errors.

The `Windows` collection takes an integer (index) or string (name) parameter to bring the corresponding window to the top. This seems to be working on the lines like `Windows("Christmas Email.xlsm").Activate`.

But the failing line is different - ´xm´ is a Range object, so `Windows(xm)` will never work. Also, the `Windows`-collection does not have a `Select` method, so even if the first part was correct, the second part would fail.

Som basic suggestions:

- always declare all variables and put `Option Explicit` at the top of the code module to enforce it - that way you will always know what type your variables are, and the line `Set xm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Back End").Range("J" & 9)` would fail before using the variable lower down, because `xm` is undeclared.
- you really don't need to activate windows, that will only slow your code down - use a Sheet reference like `sh` to access the data in the sheet.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, what your saying does make sense but I suppose my question is then - how can I access the newly named sheet to paste my template into? I did originally have both parts of my code separate which is how I know the email part works but as I was coding I decided to put them together now to iron out each issue as they pop up instead of doing it later if that makes sense.